# EF code-first how to use POCO objects in client layers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, poco

I'm new to [asp.net MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc) and [EF](http://www.asp.net/entity-framework), so excuse me if my question is not clear or easy.

I have read some tutorials about EF Code-First approach and now I'm trying this tutorial [Getting Started with EF using MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc).

Using Code-First approach I'm using the POCO classes to define my DB model, DB logic, DB validation, UI validation and some UI logic. So I can use these classes(or objects) in my presentation layer or use them as JSON objects when dealing with Web-Services(or in JavaScript code).

My question: Isn't that mixing some logic together? I mean shouldn't I use like *special* view-model classes for presentation and these classes should have the UI logic and validation ?!

Is it good practice to send the POCO object to the view(or to the client in general) ?

Finally i need some guidance on how to organize my project **layers** or **folders**? I see many ways and I'm confused about what to choose or what format I should base my own on?!!

Comment: Have you tried vs 2012 mvc samples? They are pretty neat and explonatory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use your data entities in higher layers of your application. Transform/compose/copy data from DAL into view model or business classes using a library like Automapper. This keeps the layers of your application independent and hides your database schema from end users.

Keep in mind that MVC is only concerned with presentation, all real work should happen in other layers of your app. I try to keep layers independent and use a little bit of glue code to bundle them into an app. I may write data access and business logic layers when working on MVC project, but then re-use in a command line utility. There are a lot of books that talk about writing quality code. I personally found [Clean Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882), [Code Complete 2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735619670), and [Design Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633612) extremely helpful.

Comment: but using this for each view model i need to define new class with properties that are already defined in my POCO data, right??\

Comment: It seems redundant at first, but in all but most trivial applications there will be significant differences between your persistence model and UI forms that will require specialized data structures. For example a one to many relationship is represented as Collection in your POCO, can be rendered as a string in read-only UI form, but needs to be a drop-down list with all values from related table in edit-form. Your POCO entity will not be able to handle all of these cases. It is more maintainable to keep different layers independent of one another.

Comment: i think your answer short and clear but can you recommend to me any patterns that i can use or way to organize my solution?

Answer (score 1):

As LeffeBrune said, is bad practice to show directly your data entities to the presentation layer, you can try to expose some interfaces in form of project services that return the view model to the controller. This can help to keep the layers separate, and implement Unit of Work pattern and some other cool stuff.

You can start reading the Scott Millet Book

> ASP.NET Design Patterns

for a starting point in designing a good layered application, [here](http://www.elbandit.co.uk/blog/) his blog.

Answer (score 1):

You can define interfaces in your *business layer* which your EF entities can implement; the business logic doesn't know about the actual implementation. To do this you need the *data layer* to reference the *business layer* which means you're inverting the dependencies - you then use an IoC container to bind the interfaces to their implementations. ...but yeah that's one of many, many ways to go about it.

The thing is, with *single responsibility* in mind, your entities shouldn't worry about UI stuff - this can mean your interfaces also need to be implemented by "view model" classes, which implement things like validation and other business & presentation concerns.

Comment: i didn't get the **IoC container** point, can you please explain it more?

Comment: Check out the NInject wiki, it explains it all very well. (Sorry phone post, linking isn't obvious)

Answer (score 1):

Your questions require a lot of discussions.

Choosing infrastructure for your project is a complicated issue that depends on lots of factors. There are some design patterns that address different requirements in a project which involve you or your team in multiple concepts and technologies. I recommend you two valuable resources that help you understanding software architecture focused on .Net technologies.

1. [CSLA.NET](http://www.lhotka.net/cslanet/) : The CSLA .NET framework is an application development framework that reduces the cost of building and maintaining applications. Rockford Lhotka, createor of CSLA.NET, has some books that deeply describe an optimal infrastructure of a project; all of your questions have answered in his books.
2. [Microsoft Spain - Domain Oriented N-Layered .NET 4.0 Sample App](http://microsoftnlayerapp.codeplex.com/): the project/sample is willfully restricted to .NET implementation of most used patterns in N-Layered Domain Oriented Architectures based on simple scenarios easy to understand (Customers, Orders, Bank Transfers, etc.). The project/sample is very well documented and all of your questions , also, have answered in the project.

All in all, view-models, POCOs, layers, etc. are concepts that have root in software architecture and I believe that they can not be described in short.

Answer (score 0):

What I normally use is a POCO layer to use in my data access and a view model layer to use in my views just as LeffeBrune said.
All my layers use POCOs and the controllers are responsible to construct the view model that each view needs.
To get this work more automated I use automapper.
So my solution structure gets usually to be like this:

- Model (POCO)
- Data access (NHibertante)
- Service (Business Layer)
- Web (UI)

  - ViewModel